# Is there a command line client for 8tracks.com playback?

Tags: linux, command-line, music, mplayer

I hope I'm not spamming with this kind of question here, but: is there a way to play [8tracks.com](http://www.8tracks.com) playlists from Linux command line using, for example, `mplayer` or `mpg123`?

There is the [8tracks.com API](http://www.8tracks.com/api), but so far I haven't found a command line client based on that. And as a non-coder, I don't know how to write one myself either.

I'd prefer a Perl/Python solution, but that's not crucial, though. Thanks very much for any hints!

**EDIT:** Here's a project in Haskell, but I haven't tried it myself: https://github.com/vikraman/8tracks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After reading this question, I started developing [Orochi](https://github.com/dbrgn/orochi). It's based on Python and MPlayer.

It's still in beta but search, playback, login and fave/like controls are working. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Awesome, mate, thanks a lot! Thus far I haven't encountered any errors, so it seems to work nicely on Debian 7/Python 2.7. I had kind of "abandoned" 8tracks due to the lack of a CLI app, but now I'm back. Thank you, thank you!

Comment: Are you also planning to add support for user profiles, liked mixes and, maybe indicators for how many times a mix is played and liked by other users?

Comment: Yes, user support is probably the next thing I'll implement. As for other usage issues, you're welcome to open an issue on Github if you have any ideas.

Comment: Thank you for such a great client. If anybody needs quick-and-dirty user authorization, follow the [official API](http://8tracks.com/developers/api) or just run the command `curl --request POST -d "login=USER&password=PWD" https://8tracks.com/sessions.xml`. Just replace the USER and PWD with your username and password. Then open orochi's `api.py` file and add the `X-User-Token` key to the session headers with the value of `user-token` in the server's XML response. It's a hack but it works and you only need to do it once.

Comment: @jeremija Thanks for the kind words. I'll probably implement user/auth stuff soon.